# Mixed effects model EEG data

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

My research is concerned with an Event-Related Potential (ERP) under a signal. I enrolled a sample of participants. Participants played a gambling game in which they could chose if they wanted to gamble or not at each round. If they chose not to gamble they saw the outcome of the potential gamble anyway. Before each round, a stimulus was shown on a screen that indicated the probability of winning that round. Winning probabilities took fixed levels of either 70%, 50%, or 30%.

That leaves us with 3 independent (within-subject) variables: outcome (win vs loss), realness (chose to gamble vs chose not to gamble) and stimulus, and one dependent variable: the amplitude of the particular ERP.

There were about 300-400 rounds in one session.

In total there were 3 sessions in which they played this game. Once before and once after they received deep-brain stimulation (DBS) and a third time when DBS was turned off.

That is the design of the study. My main research questions are

1. Whether the ERP changes across the three sessions
2. Whether lagged outcome, realness, and stimulus affect ERP

I decided to use a multi level model approach to compensate for missing data and to reduce noise in the data by adding random effects.

My first question is whether I should use single-trial data for the multilevel analysis or whether I should use average values for each possible combination of independent factor levels (including subject).

An example of the latter would be: subject (1); outcome (win); realness (real); probability (70%) -> ERP: 2.456 (average of all ERPs which have this combination of independent variable levels)

Lastly I am also not sure whether to encode dummy variables instead of normal ones. I would be happy for any help!

Comment: How do you have missing data?

Comment: Yes, some participants did not receive either the pre of the off testing. That is why I decided to use Mixed effects modeling in the first place

Comment: Generally when dealing with ERP data its best to rely on the average ERP since the typical background EEG signal will dominate and the ERP will only be apparent after averaging anyway. The only good justification for using the single-trials would be if you have variables that you want to account for at that level (say trial reaction time, or trial number). I don't understand what you mean by dummy vs "normal" variables. Seems like "outcome" and "realness" only have two levels anyway so doesn't matter, and probability is a continuous variable.